# How to specify the segue programmatically (NOT perform segue)?

Tags: cocoa-touch, segue

```
 AView.m
       UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame()];
       [btn addTarget:self action:@selectior(perpareForSegue:sender:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       [self.view addSubview:btn];


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
       //I want to get destinationViewController of segue with identifier"toNextView" 
       // and then perform the segue
       // Difficulties that I encounter is that I have a NSInvalidArgumentException
       // Is that mean the view controller doesn't know the existence of the segue?
       // I have connected two controller with a segue
}
```

I want to get destinationViewController of segue with identifier"toNextView" 
and then perform the segue
Difficulties that I encounter is that I have a NSInvalidArgumentException
Is that mean the view controller doesn't know the existence of the segue?
I have connected two controller with a segue.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [class reference of UIStoryboardSegue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

The method *prepareForSegue:sender:* is called by the storyboard runtime when a segue is triggered. It is not meant to be called to perform the segue.

Here is the explanation from the class reference:

> When a segue is triggered, but before the visual transition occurs,
>   the storyboard runtime calls the current view controller’s
>   prepareForSegue:sender: method **so that it can pass any needed data** to
>   the view controller that is about to be displayed.

From the class reference:

> You can still initiate a segue programmatically using the
>   performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: method of UIViewController if you
>   want. You might do so to initiate a segue from a source that was added
>   programmatically and therefore not available in Interface Builder.

So, just specify the selector for the button and then inside the selector just call *performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:* method.

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(whateverAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)whateverAction {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toNextView" sender:nil];
}
```

And if you want to pass an object to the destination view controller of the segue, that's *where prepareForSegue:sender:* method comes into play as explained in the class reference, for example:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toNextView"]) {
        DestinationViewController *vc = (DestinationViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        //do whatever you want to do with vc, including passing of data, setting property, etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is possible for me to performSegueWithIdentifier while I passing data to the destiniation view controller?

Comment: @user2429523 that's the use of prepareForSegue method. I updated my answer.

Comment: Great...it works out, addition question: how to send tag of the clicked button to the destination viewcontroller?

Comment: @user2429523 define a property in the destination view controller and set it with your tag in prepareForSegue

Comment: I have different buttons in AVIEW, is it possible to get the tag of the clicked one? (use touchesBegan?)

Comment: @user2429523 please post a separate question instead of using comments :)